# How long is the ISS visible from Earth?

Tags: atmosphere, satellites

If I‘d lie on the ground and the ISS became visible, how long could I see it (min/sec), if the circumstances were perfect and I didn't change my position?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, it does not belong on [astronomy.se], it belongs on [space.se]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on space.se